# Need Help to implement MODBUS TCP Master over Atmega32 MCU

Tags: modbus

I am doing a project where I have to interface with Fronius Solar Inverter with Atmega32 MCU over **MODBUS TCP**. I want to set the MCU as client and The inverter as Server and I have to implement two MODBUS Function only these are **READ_HOLDING_REGISTER** and **WRITE_SIGLE_REGISTER** and Function Code are **0x03** and **0x06** respectively.  I am newbie in this field and dont know about networking. Please anybody help me How can I develop the Software in C for this purpose??

The Document of Fronius Inverter for MODBUS TCP is [Fronius MODBUS TCP Datamanger](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7NXiG9jOGhmbFpMckJkNDFMdEE)

Comment: Create A TCP connection (your inverter is TCP server) [Check this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket), your device got modbus pattern so not modbus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you want to the atmega as client this means it will start the conection and made the request for values, so translating into modbus words your atmega will be a modbus master and the solar will be a modbus slave.

first you need a way to interface the micocontroller to the tcp/ip stack. you can use an ic or arduino shield which has this ic like a w5100 or enc28j60.

then you can write a library over tcp sockets to start the comunication or change some from the arduino.

https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://myarduinoprojects.com/modbus.html&ved=0ahUKEwj9zMvjiYDTAhXJkpAKHfsNBz0QFggpMAE&usg=AFQjCNEfRhDgPGJNK-IUqrUw1FXEnBcxwQ&sig2=Xs0JNEWi_F_XiPgkTQdy-w

Comment: Thank You @Luiz Henrique Diniz Ferreira  for your Kind Information. Is this good and working Library for Arduino Client?. If it is woks good on Arduino as Client then I will drag from Atmega32 to Arduino.

Comment: this link  http://myarduinoprojects.com/modbus.html has a library for using on arduino, i didn't tested it but maybe should work. You can install it, and if you are using windows download a program called modbus poll which simulate devices on a modbus network, first try with the program and then the fronius, this way u can deal with less errors at once.